# C# change bool type in tuple when specific Error type is occurred

Tags: c#

I have this Tuple

```
return new Tuple<bool, List<Error>, List<Error>>(false, errors, validErr);
```

I want to set bool to true if error type is `TimeoutException`

I tried to solve problem like this

```
TimeoutException err = null

if(err is TimeoutException )

return new Tuple<bool, List<Error>, List<Error>>(true, errors, validErr);
}
else {
return new Tuple<bool, List<Error>, List<Error>>(false, errors, validErr);
}
```

I am not sure if this is correct or not. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What does not work on your approach? You can catch exceptions with try-catch

Comment: Please provide more context to the question. It seems you have a whole list of errors. When do you want to set the bool as true? When all of the errors are timeouts or when at least one is a timeout or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ternary operator to achieve it in less line of code.

```
 TimeoutException err = null
 bool hasTimeoutException = err is TimeoutException ? true : false;
 return new Tuple<bool, List<Error>, List<Error>>(hasTimeoutException, errors, validErr);
```

or you can directly add that ternary operator in return statement like below:

```
 return new Tuple<bool, List<Error>, List<Error>>(err is TimeoutException ? true : false, errors, validErr);
```

Comment: or just `err is TimeoutException`. No need for `? true : false` since it's already boolean.